# Webmatrix download from remote DotNetNuke (DNN) site hangs without error

Tags: dotnetnuke, webmatrix

I am working on a site for a client that was created in DOTNETNUKE (DNN) and WebMatrix.  I need to download a copy of the site to my local machine so I can open it in Visual Studio 2012 access the codebehind.  The download gets to about 85% complete and then hangs without giving me an error.

This is my first experience with both WebMatrix and DNN.  Does anyone know how I can find out what is causing the download to hang?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do a local installation of DNN, or if you want, pull down a backup of the Files and Database for the client's site, then restore that locally.

If you have FTP access to the server check out this video for how to backup items

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Community/Learn/Video-Library/View-Video/Video/243/View/Details/Backing-up-a-DotNetNuke-Website-via-FTP

Here is a link to the Installation instructions for DNN

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Install_DotNetNuke

You will also want to learn how to Upgrade DNN as the client's site is likely behind on the latest releases of DNN

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Upgrading-DotNetNuke

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to install and run DNN locally.  I was also finally able to download a backup of the client's site.  However, when I try to build the website in VS the build fails and gives this error;

'GetString' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.